# How do you have the maven swagger codegen plugin generate Java classes using inheritance?

Tags: java, maven, swagger, swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

In our swagger.yaml file, we have a definition `Cat` that uses `allOf` to include all properties of `Pet`.

```
Cat:
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/definitions/Pet'
    - type: object
      properties:
      # ...
```

The **expectation** is that when generating Java sources, we get

```
public class Cat extends Pet {
```

This works when using the [Swagger Editor](https://editor.swagger.io).

When using `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` with no `configOptions` set, we get the following:

```
public class Cat {
```

`Cat` implements all of `Pet`'s properties itself, instead of extending it.

**How do you tell the `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` to use Java with inheritance (i.e. `extends`)?** (We tried both spring and java as languages.)

Here's a sample swagger.yaml file:

```
swagger: '2.0'

info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: simple inheritance

tags:
  - name: "pet"

paths:
  /cat:
    put:
      tags:
        - "pet"
      operationId: "updateCat"
      consumes:
        - "application/json"
      parameters:
        - in: "body"
          name: "body"
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Cat"
      responses:
        200:
          description: Nada

definitions:
  Pet:
    type: "object"
    required:
      - "name"
    properties:
      name:
        type: "string"
        example: "doggie"
  Cat:
    allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/Pet'
      - type: object
        properties:
          huntingSkill:
            type: string
        required:
          - huntingSkill
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out on github by [chiochuan](https://github.com/chiochuan), the workaround is to add

```
   discriminator: "type"
```

to the parent's definition to make the Java child classes extend it.

```
definitions:
  Pet:
    type: "object"
    discriminator: "type"
    required:
      - "name"
    properties:
      name:
        type: "string"
        example: "doggie"
```

It's a bit strange as the OpenAPI Specification Version 2.0 state that the [`discriminator` Fixed Field](https://swagger.io/specification/v2/#fixed-fields-13) must reference a property from the same schema, and that it must be a `required` property, both of which isn't the case - but it works, at least as of today. :)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you don't want to include "**configOptions**"? The swagger-codegen-maven-plugin version 4.3.1 works with the following configuration.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
  <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>spring-boot-api</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <inputSpec>YOUR_SPEC_FILE</inputSpec>
        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
        <configOptions>
          <skipDefaultInterface>true</skipDefaultInterface>
          <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
          <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
          <sourceFolder>src/main/java</sourceFolder>
        </configOptions>
        <library>spring-boot</library>
        <apiPackage>com.api</apiPackage>
        <modelPackage>com.api.model</modelPackage>
        <invokerPackage>com.api.handler</invokerPackage>
        <typeMappings>
          <typeMapping>OffsetDateTime=LocalDateTime</typeMapping>
        </typeMappings>
        <importMappings>
          <importMapping>java.time.OffsetDateTime=java.time.LocalDateTime</importMapping>
        </importMappings>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```